Why can't the verb 'Need" accept passive Gerunds
Why can't the verb 'need" accept passive Gerunds?

My car needs washing - correct
My car needs to be washed - correct
My car needs being washed - incorrect

Why can't a passive Gerund fit in there?
Are there any more verbs that behave like 'need?'
Thanks,
A_Mendes

What passive gerund would you like? You mean "my car needs being washed"? It's just not done.

"My car needs washed."  This is found (among others) in the Pennsylvania Dutch area of the US.

@StuartF I know that. What is the reason?

@GEdgar Yes. I have read about it. But that is wrong and is not what we expect with other verbs. "She doesn't like being ridiculed."  (not 'she doesn't like ridiculed').

My car needs washed is related to Pennyslvania Dutch, not English. It's like the Yiddish already-type thing. Don't do that already!

"why" questions like this are almost impossible to answer, English doesn't operate according to strict rules. Some things are just not idiomatic, and there's little reason for it. Verbs of perception seem to behave similarly, you can't say "I saw being washed" (but you can say "I saw the car being washed").

@Barmar  That is weird. "I saw being washed." There is something called an object to fit in there. That does not have any faintest relation with my question. As far as the reason, there must be something somewhere either in CGEL, Quark... or Oxford grammar. If not, maybe someone might be able to list similar verbs.

I thought I was giving you similar verbs: see, hear, feel.

@Barmar. They are not similar. I saw her being beaten. I heard the song being sung. I felt cheated. ( Feel is a stative verb . So I think it won't take continuous tense)

But that's different, because you added a direct object. Your question is about the passive gerund being applied to the sentence subject.

@Araucaria-Him — Since you asked the question you are referring to, and since you did not accept an answer there, and since the question is closed... What is the answer to this OP’s “not-different” question?

It’s a mess over there — question(s) and (un)answers alike. I’m voting to reopen this one.

In My car needs washing, washing is already passive. CGEL calls it a “concealed passive”:

2.3 Concealed passives (The house needs painting)
With a small number of catenative verbs, notably need, require,
deserve, and want, a gerund-participial may be passive while lacking the usual marking of the passive – we refer to this as the
concealed passive construction. Compare:
[ordinary passive]
[16]  i  a.  The house needs to be painted. 
            
b. These books want to be taken back to the library.
[concealed passive]
        ii  a.  The
house needs painting.
            b.
 These books want taking back to the library.
Source: The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language


"want taking back" doesn't sound natural to me.

@Barmar — I agree it sounds pretty odd. British!

Yes; "want taking back"  sounds natural to me (conversational register). Want = require.

Hmm... It is there as a concealed passive in Wkipedia as well. However, I asked this because it can take another form of passive (passive infinitive). Quoting: "In the concealed passive, the present participle or gerund form (-ing form) appears rather than the past participle. This can appear after need, and for some speakers after want (with similar meaning). For example:
Your car needs washing. (meaning "needs to be washed")
That rash needs looking at by a specialist.
(An idiomatic expression with the same construction is ... doesn't bear thinking about.)"
